# Sending mail to the website authorities via JavaMail

Tags: jakarta-mail

I'm building a J2EE webapp in where the user should be able to send email to the website authorities. It's simple enough to send a mail via JavaMail. But there I would have to ask the user for his/her password and email ID. Moreover, is it possible for the user to send mail from any email account?or should it be ones which i specify?

Answer (score 0):

If the user of your app is sending email to you to notify you of something related to the app, the app should probably be using an email user/password that you own.  You can include information in the message that indicates which user of your app is sending the message.  Depending on the mail server you're using, it might allow you to set the app user's email address as the From address of the message, even though you're using your own user/password to login to the mail server when you send the message.